# Workaround for lack of return type covariance when overriding virtual methods

Tags: c#, methods, covariance, vtable

is there any way to 'hack' or 'coerce' covariant overrides in to C#?

For example:

```
public class Alpha {
    public virtual Alpha DoSomething() {
        return AlphaFactory.GetAlphaFromSomewhere();
    }
}
public class Beta : Alpha {
    public override Beta DoSomething() {
        return BetaFactory.GetBetaFromSomewhere();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, C# doesn't support this (which seems a bit ridiculous, but that's neither here nor there).

I thought I might have an answer with method hiding:

```
new public Beta DoSomething() {
    return BetaFactory.GetBetaFromSomewhere();
}
```

But this doesn't add the entry in to the 'vtable', it just basically declares a brand new method with the same name, and as such means that accessing `Beta`s through a pointer to an `Alpha` will call `Alpha.DoSomething()`.

So, any good tricks?

Comment: Why do you need to change the return value? What is not meeting your needs in having `Beta.DoSomething()` return an `Alpha` typed object? As long as the right methods are defined as virtual in `Alpha` and then overridden in `Beta`, it doesn't really matter; any call to a virtual method will resolve to the runtime type of the object, not the compile time type.

Comment: Isn't casting enough of a "hack"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do some pretty zany stuff with generics.

```
public class Alpha<T> where T: Alpha<T> {
    public virtual T DoSomething() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Beta : Alpha<Beta> {
    public override Beta DoSomething() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: A generic abuse to gain exactly what?

Comment: If you have a static reference to `Beta`, you don't need to do a runtime cast to get a `Beta` reference from `DoSomething`.

Comment: Oh, so you over complicate the whole type system with this generic headache to simply avoid the cheapest possible cast (safe too)?

Comment: This is hilarious, and kudos to you. I suppose if Alpha was internal rather than public it could be viable... I suppose you could extrapolate on this and extend Alpha from some internal class... But yeah, it's not too nice, haha. :)

Comment: @Motig SO is a place where people spend some if their time trying to help others. I don't really appreciate you qualifying my efforts as "patronising crap". Have a nice day.

Comment: This is known in C++ as the CRTP - curiously recurring template pattern. This is the equivalent in C#. @recursive you have a perfect username for this answer!

Comment: Here's a helpful article with another example and discussion: https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/01/c-builder-pattern-with-inheritance/

Answer (score 1):

You can always wrap the method inside another method

```
public class Alpha {
    public virtual Alpha DoSomething() {
        return AlphaFactory.GetAlphaFromSomewhere();
    }
}
public class Beta : Alpha {
    private Beta Helper() {
        return BetaFactory.GetBetaFromSomewhere();
    }
    public Beta DoSomething() {
        return Helper();
    }
    public override Alpha DoSomething() {
        return Helper();
    }
}
```

If there are lots of methods though, you might want to autogenerate these wrappers. If that's too demanding, the solution of @recursive is all there is left.

Answer (score -1):

Because there is no great benefit in return type covariance in most cases.

If you are calling virtual `Alpha.DoSomething` then you really don't know if you are getting back an `Alpha` or a `Beta` so how does return type covariance help? You will have to store the result in an `Alpha` typed object anyhow because it's the only type that can admit `Alpha`s or `Beta`s.

On the other hand, if you *statically know* that you are calling `Beta.DoSomething` then you can either: directly use the returned `Alpha` typed object because you will be accessing common functionality or virtual methods so you don't care if it's really a `Beta` (the virtual call will resolve to the right type) or you can directly choose to (runtime safe) cast to `Beta` in order to access specific implementation.

*Edit*: removed the type safe issue. I barely thought it through and evidently return type covariance would be safe. The rest of the answer stands though. I can't find anything particularly interesting in this feature, at least in the way the OP wants to use it: avoid a safe cheap cast?

Comment: Java can do this out of the box (it lets you change the return type of non-final methods in subclasses so long as the return type is a subclass of the return type in the base class).  I think the blithe dismissal of the OP's concern as "no great benefit" is a bit offputting.

Comment: @KirkWoll [All C# features start with -100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx), it just did not get enough points.

Comment: @KirkWoll just because Java does it out of the box doesn't necessarily make it a compelling reason. The broken variance of arrays in C# is due to its existence in Java too...was that a good design decision? I might be wrong and return type variance is a great feature to have in a language so please tell me why. Your comment is niether constructive nor does it add anything helpful to this topic.

Comment: @InBetween, through all your myriad comments on this question I've gotten the vibe you think the feature the OP sought was generally a useless idea.  It seems self-evident that if you have an instance of `Beta` and are invoking an overridden method directly on `Beta` -- that *`Beta`* knows must be a more specific subtype of the return type declared in `Alpha` -- then it's convenient if it could declare that it returns that type.

Comment: @KirkWoll Of course I understand that. If you've read my answer its obvious. My point is that I don't find it a mind blowing feature to the point of qualifying it as, I quote the OP, ridiculous, that C# doesn't support it. After all most of the time you'll probably be fine with the virtual call through Alpha and when that is not the case you can do the cheapest possible cast that will always succeed in runtime. A language that doesn't support this feature is not lacking anything mind blowing or even mildly annoying IMHO.That's all I was trying to convey through my myriad of comments.

Comment: @KirkWoll Anyhow we can agree to disagree on this issue ;) topic is not really worth discussing it any further.